# UIButton's textLabel not being clipped

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton,and I set its text like this:

```
let myButton ...
myButton.textLabel?.text = "abcdefghijklmn"
```

But when I run it ,the text is clipped. How could UIButton auto resize to fit its inner text.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

What I want is this:

abcdefghijklmn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option A: myButton.sizeToFit()

Option B: use layout constraints that don't constrict the label's width

Comment: The button is created from storyboard, and in viewDidload method, I change its title via setTitle method,and call the sizeToFit method on myButton.But nothing happens.